# Google Script e.values unable to trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have multiple forms in my spreadsheet. Below is a snapshot of trigger. All of the codes are written at spreadsheet.

```
//only run once to set the trigger
//ScriptApp.newTrigger('QuotationFormSubmitTrigger').forForm('1zDMtv46H-nHqG4_Z1lNAACClNWe-RBZs9PtDKoqdWrc').onFormSubmit().create();
```

The script is supposed to duplicate a quotation template and fill in all the form info once the quotation form is submitted. below is the snapshot of code where I am stuck. Each time e.values is enabled, the whole code will not work.

```
function QuotationFormSubmitTrigger(e) {

//console.log(values);
//quotationID = argument[0];
//Logger.log(quotationID);
//copy quotation template file
//open quotation template file
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1vwcpoKXCp27fRYWwC7qBoIgxDNU2Yx_Bk4UTvBPXF9Y");
var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1C3e5CpZzti5XhpPh2Kx7vlXdQ9ltdb24");

//var timestamp = e.values[0];
//var companyName = e.values[1];
//var quotationID = e.values[2];
//var contactName = e.values[4];
//product1 = values[5];
//product1qty = values[6];

//make a copy of template file and rename
riveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy('testID', destFolder);

}
```

Comment: Are you running it manually?

Comment: Please check for error under view->execution transcripts.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: nope i am running through a form submission. the execution transcripts shows all failed runs when e is enabled.

Comment: i found the problem and it lies with the trigger. it is triggered at form side. after i cahnge to the sheet, everything works flawlessly. any way to make a trigger at spreadsheet side and only for a particular form? rather than being trigger for all forms.

ScriptApp.newTrigger('QuotationFormSubmitTrigger').forForm('1zDMtv46H-nHqG4_Z1lNAACClNWe-RBZs9PtDKoqdWrc').onFormSubmit().create();

Comment: With onFormSubmit for a spreadsheet you can use the range to determine which range was edited and therefor e.range.getSheet() gives you the sheet that was edited and from that you can determine which form it was from